# What is the /pub/static in Magento2? I am trying to find the Header.phtml?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento2

Am I correct in assuming that /pub/static is rendered somehow by GruntJS and Less and this is an automated compilation of some sort - or can I directly edit these files or are they cache based? Would appreciate some light on how this renders and works?

I am looking for the default header.phtml files. So far I have only found 1column.xml and 2column.xml etc - I don't really like the XML files and editing them. I just want to access the raw header.phtml in the Blank theme if there is one and also some light on the above question

Thanks

Comment: U should not edit these files.it will override next deploy.these are cached files

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to put static files in /pub/static directory depending on application mode you using. You can find the mode using

> ./bin/magento deploy:mode:show

- Developer and default modes use "pub/static.php" file to materialize static files in run time. Only files included in visited page will be deployed.
- In production mode you need to execute "./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" command in order to materialize all static files.

However your phtml file is not static and wont be deployed here. The original file is located here app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml. This file could be overridden in your theme.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further on your answer showing server examples of structure on if I changed a LESS file and also if I changed a live phtml file - do I need to run the deploy tool again or will Magento know? Real examples of development to live please and using grunt deploy.

Answer (score 1):

simple go to **app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html** and copy the header.phtml and past to your theme in this path **app/design/frontend/YouVendor/YouTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html** folder

if you using blank theme directly past inside `app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/Magento_Theme/templates/html`

**Note:** you can use the same technique for layout files , other choice for example if you not find folder templates and html you need create..